# How to avoid format in "XDocument.Parse(strHtml)"

Tags: c#, html

When i tried to remove unwanted html span tags my code working fine but its getting formatted so its occur alignment error
Before XDocument.Parse:

```
 strHtml = '<html><body><p>Liver - The liver is diffuse hypoechoic and mildly enlarged. No masses or nodules seen. No obvious congested vessels.</p><p /><p>Gall bladder/biliary tract - Normal</p><p /><p>Spleen - Normal</p><p /><p>Kidneys - Bilateral few tiny cortical cysts</p><p /><p>Right - 6.7cm</p><p /><p>Left - 6.3cm</p><p /><p>Adrenal Glands -</p><p /><p>Right- 0.41cm</p><p /><p>Left - 0.51cm</p><p /><p>Bladder - Normal</p><p /><p>Gastrointestinal - The stomach near field wall appears normal. The stomach contains gas which precludes imaging of the far field. Normal small and large intestines</p><p /><p>Lymph nodes - Normal</p><p /><p>Pancreas - Diffuse hyperechoic patchy pancreas</p><p /><p>Reproductive - atrophied prostate</p><p /><p>Other - no free fluid; no obvious pericardial effusion</p><p /><p>Ultrasound Findings:</p><p /><p>1) Hyperechoic, patchy pancreatic parenchyma- r/o chronic pancreatitis vs. fibrosis</p><p /><p>2) Rare tiny kidney cyst</p><p /><p>3) Diffuse hypoechoic mild hepatomegaly</p></body></html>'
```

After XDocument.Parse:

```
    html=   
    '<html>
      <body>
        <p>Liver - The liver is diffuse hypoechoic and mildly enlarged. No masses or nodules seen. No obvious congested vessels.</p>
        <p />
        <p>Gall bladder/biliary tract - Normal</p>
        <p />
        <p>Spleen - Normal</p>
        <p />
        <p>Kidneys - Bilateral few tiny cortical cysts</p>
        <p />
        <p>Right - 6.7cm</p>
        <p />       
        <p>3) Diffuse hypoechoic mild hepatomegaly</p>
      </body>
    </html>'
```

I dont want to format anything should return same like strHtml

Below code i am using for remove unwanted html tags. my expectation is dont want to format html elements just return mentioned above "strHtml"

```
public static string RemoveEmptyHtmlTags(string strHtml)
        {
            var html = XDocument.Parse(strHtml);
            var spanElements = html.Descendants("span").ToList();
            for (int i = spanElements.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (spanElements[i].Value == "") spanElements[i].Remove();
            return html.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Try : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)  There is also an Encode method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this overload of `ToString` inherited from `XNode`:

```
public string ToString (System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions options);
```

like

```
return html.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Comment: `var html = XDocument.Parse(strHtml);` does not format. It converts a string containing XML to a `XDocument` representing a document object model. This is not a string at this time. It consists of linked and nested nodes. When you then call `html.ToString(...)`, this creates a **new** string.